# Parse the first level keys of $_POST, then use the numeric suffix while looping

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key, text-parsing

I have a form that contains a number of fields with names item1, item2, item13, item43 etc, each time those fields are different because they are populated in the form with AJAX.

When user submits I need to perform the following:

```
foreach ($_POST['itemX']['tagsX'] as $tag) {
    inserttag($tag, X);
}
```

where X = 1,2,13,43 etc. How can I iterate the $_POST values and perform the above only for the values of those that their name begins with 'item' followed by an the X identifier?

The posted data has the following format:

```
$_POST = [
    'item38' => ['tags38' => ['aaa', 'bbb']],
    'item40' => ['tags40' => ['ccc', 'ddd']],
    'item1' => ['tags1' => ['eee', 'zzz']],
];
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (strstr($key, 'item'))
    {
        $x = str_replace('item','',$key);
        inserttag($value, $x);
    }
}
```

Comment: The PHP documentation has an explicit note that says not to use `strstr()` to check the existence of a substring for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through `$_POST` with `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { ... }
```

And within the loop you can evaluate whether each key found by the loop matches your criteria. Something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   if (substr($key, 0, 4) == "item") {
      $identifier = substr($key, 4);
      if (isset($value['tag' . $identifier])) { inserttag('tag', $identifier); }
   }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what is actually real and what is just a placeholder in your question though. Maybe I took something for solid fact that actually isn't. You might need to explain your wishes in more detail. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    inserttag($key, $value);
}
```

`$key` will be the name of the element and `$value` will be the value.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `$_POST` and see if the key contains `'item'`.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(preg_match('/item(\d*)/', $key, $match) === 1){
        inserttag($value, $match[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to iterate through `$value` looking for keys that match `tagsX` then pass those values to `inserttag`

Comment: I was just thinking this @Musa!

Comment: @Musa: Reading the question again, yeah, sounds like I would.  I'll leave that as a challenge for the OP ^^

Comment: Please check my question, I've updated it with the solution. Thanks everyone for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sscanf()` to validate and extract the identifying integer with one function call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UruI9))

```
foreach ($_POST as $itemId => $set) {
    if (sscanf($itemId, 'item%d', $id)) {
        foreach ($set["tags$id"] as $v) {
            inserttag($v, $id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your item numbers are sequential, it's possible to use FOR to this intent. Concatenate the number ($i) with the item name on the index, like that:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $numbeOfItems; $i++) {
 inserttag($_POST['item' . $i]['tags' . $i]), $i;
}
```

Comment: The asked question does not indicate that the input array is indexed.